# Move DIV on Load and Resize with Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get this script to move the HTML from point A to point B on mobile (767px and below). It doesn't seem to work however. I've selected both the element by ID, and the innerHTML but I haven't seemed to have luck.

```
var addEvent = function(object, type, callback) {
    if (object == null || typeof(object) == 'undefined') return;
    if (object.addEventListener) {
        object.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    } else if (object.attachEvent) {
        object.attachEvent("on" + type, callback);
    } else {
        object["on"+type] = callback;
    }
};
var element;

element = document.getElementById('pointA');
recalcHTML();
addEvent(window, "resize", recalcHTML());


function recalcHTML() {
    var element = element;
    var target  = document.getElementById('pointB');
    if (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth <= 767) {
        target.appendChild(element);
    } else {
        element.appendChild(target);
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pointA"><img src="/images/example.jpg" alt="" width="300" /></div>
<div id="pointB"></div>
```

Comment: Post html code also or working fiddle. It will be east for us to resolve.

Comment: @Sharmila Done.